# How to make an input box centered in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, styling

I am currently writing an app in Ionic where you enter a number and select a language it will print out the number in another language. I have got it all working, and I am now styling it. I have got all of it centered, except for my input box. I have researched a lot but can't find anything that is the same.
Here is some of my HTML:

```
  <ion-content class="padding" id="ion-content">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row  center">
<div class="col"><h1>Please Enter Your Phone Number:</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-100 center" style="display:block;">
<input type="tel" ng-model="number" class="borders" name="number">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row center">
  <div class="col">
  <select id="select" ng-model="language">
    <option value="French">FRENCH</option>
    <option value="German">GERMAN</option>
    <option value="English">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="Mandarin">MANDARIN</option>
    <option value="Swedish">SWEDISH</option>
    <option value="Latin">LATIN</option>
    <option value="Bulgarian">BULGARIAN</option>
    <option value="Turkish">TURKISH</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row center"><div class="col">
  <button class="Nextbutton" ng-click="doit(number,language)">
<h1>TRANSLATE</h1></button>
</div>
```

(that is all that is relevant to my issue)
Here is my CSS:

```
    body{

    }
    .center {
    text-align:center;
    }

    .firstinput {

    }

    h1 {
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    #change {
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .borders {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    border-color:black;

    }
select {
  margin:10px;
  font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input-label {
  width:30%;
}
```

There is also some Javascript but I don't think that that will be an issue for this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

just add your center class to your input

```css
body{

    }
    .center {
    text-align:center;
    }

    .firstinput {

    }

    h1 {
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    }
    #change {
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .borders {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:10px;
    font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    border-color:black;

    }
select {
  margin:10px;
  font-family:Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input-label {
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row  center">
<div class="col"><h1>Please Enter Your Phone Number:</h1></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-100 center" style="display:block;">
<input type="tel" ng-model="number" class="borders center" name="number">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row center">
  <div class="col">
  <select id="select" ng-model="language">
    <option value="French">FRENCH</option>
    <option value="German">GERMAN</option>
    <option value="English">ENGLISH</option>
    <option value="Mandarin">MANDARIN</option>
    <option value="Swedish">SWEDISH</option>
    <option value="Latin">LATIN</option>
    <option value="Bulgarian">BULGARIAN</option>
    <option value="Turkish">TURKISH</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row center"><div class="col">
  <button class="Nextbutton" ng-click="doit(number,language)">
<h1>TRANSLATE</h1></button>
</div>
```

Comment: No sorry that didn't work, I think it's to do with ionic built-in classes, because when I run the snippet in stack overflow it works, but when you have all of ionic's CSS it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter, it just needed to be inline-block

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it... I just needed to make the element an inline-block